# Facing problems while fetching contacts in android?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am developing an android app which has a button in one activity and when user clicks that button it should create another activity which should show all my contact information in my own ListView.
My code is as follows

```
package com.softtrends.practice.contactmanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ContactManagerActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST=1;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Button contacts=(Button) findViewById(R.id.contacts);
    contacts.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    Intent contactIntent = new Intent(this, ContactsActivity.class);
    startActivity(contactIntent);
}
}

package com.softtrends.practice.contactmanager;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ContactsActivity extends ListActivity {
private Cursor cur;
private String names[];
private void getData(){
    cur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, 
                              null, null,null, null);
    startManagingCursor(cur);
    names=new String[cur.getCount()];
    int nameCol=cur.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int i=0;
    while(cur.moveToNext()){
        names[i]=cur.getString(nameCol);
        System.out.println(names[i]);
        i++;
    }
    cur.close();
}
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
    super.onCreate(bundle);
getData();
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_view, names));

    ListView lv=getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
} 
}
```

While running this app, it displays the first activity as expected but when I click the button, Force close error is coming and in the logcat the error is showing at the line where I am calling the query method.

My logcat is

```
 01-25 14:07:05.239: DEBUG/dalvikvm(127): GC_EXPLICIT freed 179 objects / 9288 bytes in 163ms
    01-25 14:07:09.249: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent{ cmp=  com.softtrends.practice.contactmanager/.ContactsActivity }
    01-25 14:07:09.389: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(164): Writing exception to parcel
    01-25 14:07:09.389: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(164): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/contacts from pid=386, uid=10040 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
    01-25 14:07:09.389: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(164):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:271)
    01-25 14:07:09.389: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(164):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.bulkQuery(ContentProvider.java:149)
    01-25 14:07:09.389: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(164):     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:111)
    01-25 14:07:09.389: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(164):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:288)
    01-25 14:07:09.389: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(164):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
    01-25 14:07:09.389: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(386): Shutting down VM
    01-25 14:07:09.389: WARN/dalvikvm(386): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
    01-25 14:07:09.420: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-25 14:07:09.420: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.softtrends.practice.contactmanager/com.softtrends.practice.contactmanager.ContactsActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/contacts from pid=386, uid=10040 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
    01-25 14:07:09.420: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
    01-25 14:07:09.420: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    01-25 14:07:09.420: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
    01-25 14:07:09.420: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
    01-25 14:07:09.420: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    01-25 14:07:09.420: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    01-25 14:07:09.420: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    01-25 14:07:09.420: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-25 14:07:09.420: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    01-25 14:07:09.420: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    01-25 14:07:09.420: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    01-25 14:07:09.420: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    01-25 14:07:09.420: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/contacts from pid=386, uid=10040 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
    01-25 14:07:09.420: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1247)
    01-25 14:07:09.420: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:160)
    01-25 14:07:09.420: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:114)
    01-25 14:07:09.420: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.bulkQueryInternal(ContentProviderNative.java:330)
    01-25 14:07:09.420: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:366)
    01-25 14:07:09.420: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:245)
    01-25 14:07:09.420: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at com.softtrends.practice.contactmanager.ContactsActivity.onCreate(ContactsActivity.java:29)
    01-25 14:07:09.420: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    01-25 14:07:09.420: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
    01-25 14:07:09.420: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     ... 11 more
    01-25 14:07:09.439: WARN/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing activity com.softtrends.practice.contactmanager/.ContactsActivity
    01-25 14:07:09.439: WARN/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing activity com.softtrends.practice.contactmanager/.ContactManagerActivity
    01-25 14:07:09.579: DEBUG/dalvikvm(59): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 11214 objects / 557344 bytes in 116ms
    01-25 14:07:09.839: DEBUG/SntpClient(59): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
    01-25 14:07:09.980: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{450d30d0 com.softtrends.practice.contactmanager/.ContactsActivity}
    01-25 14:07:15.710: DEBUG/dalvikvm(164): GC_EXPLICIT freed 121 objects / 13752 bytes in 148ms
    01-25 14:07:20.443: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{4509d8d0 com.softtrends.practice.contactmanager/.ContactManagerActivity}
    01-25 14:07:20.443: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{450d30d0 com.softtrends.practice.contactmanager/.ContactsActivity}
```

some may think that as per the logcat it requires READ_CONTACTS permission. But let me tell all that I have already set this permission in my menifest file. Here is my manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.softtrends.practice.contactmanager"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".ContactManagerActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ContactsActivity"></activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: sorry dear for not mentioning the logcat but I have already mentioned the error is at the line cur=getContentResolver().query(...). While debuging the application after this line is debugged the variable cur should contain the reference of a Cursor object but in my case the cur variable contains null. That means the RHS of that line has some problem.

Comment: You need to learn to read the log message. Logcat mentioned it requires **android.permission.READ_CONTACTS** .

Comment: I have already configured the permission in my manifest file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank God finally I got the answer, it's a silly mistake, the answer is instead of **uses-permission** tag I used **user-permission** tag in the manifest file.

Answer (score 2):

As the log says, you need android.permission.READ_CONTACTS so add this to manifest:

```
<manifest>
....
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
</manifest>
```

and if you need the write too, add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

Comment: Yes sure but I have already set that permission in my manifest file. Please see my code and say where the problem lies.